# Send parameters as an array, not separately. (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my project, I have a series of checkbox inputs. When users check/uncheck them, the I use `$.get` in javascript to send the values to a different page.

What I mean is:

```
<form id="category_search">
  <input name="category" type="checkbox" id="1" value="1"> <label for="1"> Cat1 </label>
  <input name="category" type="checkbox" id="2" value="2"> <label for="2"> Cat2 </label>
  <input name="category" type="checkbox" id="3" value="3"> <label for="3"> Cat3 </label>
  ...
</form>
```

When they are clicked, I use `$("#category_search").serialize()` to get the checked values and send them to the different page.

But when they are sent, they are shown in the url as:

```
category=1&category=2&category=3
```

I would like to send them altogether (as an array?) like the following:

```
category=1,2,3
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your `name="category"` to `name="categories[]"` note: `[]` show that it's array

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the name attribute from `category` to `categories[]`. Now the params are shown in the url as `categories[]=1&categories[]=2. It did not do the job.

Comment: in this case you will have proper array, does it matter how it looks if you send it via `$.get`? if yes you could format it as you want with js.

Comment: Hmm.. you are right. I do have a proper array when I try your method. Thank you.